# check if already replied to a tweet

Tags: python, api, tweepy

I am trying to have this bot to reply to a user latest tweet, however, the bot keep replying to the last tweet multiple times. To fix it I created a list to store the tweets ID's, and then check if the latest tweet exist in the list before replying, but for some reason its still reply multiple times

```
    def on_status(self, status):
    timelineTweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name="USERNAME")
    alreadyReplied=[-1]
    
    if timelineTweets[0].id not in alreadyReplied:
        lastTweet = timelineTweets[0]
        api.update_status('@USERNAME' + gettext(),in_reply_to_status_id = lastTweet.id)
        alreadyReplied.append(lastTweet.id)
        if len(alreadyReplied)==20:
            alreadyReplied.pop()
        return True
```